# Do I need to install any additional library to use Array.Parallel.map in F# running on Mono?

Tags: .net, f#, mono, parallel-processing

I built mono-2.10.2 from source and installed the fsharp packages from http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/. But I have this program which runs without error on Windows but not on Linux/Mono. It complains about the following error:

`error FS0039: The value, onstructor, namespace or type 'Parallel' is not defined`

The parallel extensions seem to be still missing.

Comment: While this may seem like an obvious question to you, it's not obvious to us. 1.) Share some source 2.) Which instructions did you follow when you installed F#? 3.) Which version of Mono did you pull--the tip of the tree or a stable release?

Comment: What Mono version do you have?

Comment: On Windows, I can do `Array.Parallel.map ((+) 2) [| 1 |];;` directly on F# interactive `fsi.exe`, but not on Linux.
I installed the fsharp packages from http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/. I believe the parallel extensions are not installed properly? Not sure how to check.

Comment: Latest mono-2.10.2.tar.bz2 from http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/sources-stable/.

Comment: You're probably right that parallel extensions are missing. Check it in `fsi` by typing `open System.Threading.Tasks;;`. Why don't you use [package releases](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html)? Mono 2.10.x package releases include F# already.

Comment: Yes, it can't find it: `error FS0039: The namespace 'Tasks' is not defined`. My Linux distro is not supported, so I've to compile from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, no.

I have installed [Mono 2.10.4 package release](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) which includes F# package by default. Parallel extensions are working fine so I can use `Array.Parallel.map`.

In your case, my guess is that [fsharp package](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/) is outdated and doesn't include parallel extensions. You should install F# from source by using the up-to-date and Mono-friendly version in [github](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp). A detailed instruction of doing so could be found [here](http://www.srtsolutions.com/f-on-ubuntu-linux-with-mono-and-monodevelop).

Comment: (fragmentation of fsharp code and extensions is quite a puzzle)

Comment: @pad indeed the fsharp package did not include the parallel extensions. I installed from source and it worked.